# fix adonisjs Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

In postman I received the following error:

> Unexpected token '.'
>
> app\Controllers\Http\UtilisateurController.js:1:1
> C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\kya\projectsCode\backend\app\Controllers\Http\UtilisateurController.js

[image]

```
'use strict'

/** @typedef {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Request')} Request */
/** @typedef {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Response')} Response */
/** @typedef {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/View')} View */

/**
 * Resourceful controller for interacting with utilisateurs
 */
const Utilisateur = use('App/Models/Utilisateur');
const TypeUtilisateur = use('App/Models/TypeUtilisateur');

class UtilisateurController {

     //........

    async getUtilisateurByUserId ({ params, request, response, view }) {

        console.log("========DISPLAY=========")

       let utilisateur = await Utilisateur.findBy('user_id', request.input('user_id')) 
       return response.json(utilisateur);
    }

     //........

}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console log? Can you share your full controller & specific `route.js` code?

Comment: ok. Even i make console.log(), nothing appear

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I resolved it. the problem was the ? i put inside, const tu = (await TypeUtilisateur.findBy('titre','admin'))?.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the **?** i put inside

const tu = (await TypeUtilisateur.findBy('titre','admin'))**?**.id